# Scala for-comprehension syntax

Tags: scala, tuples, for-comprehension

In the following code, inside the `for` comprehension, I can refer to the string and index using a tuple dereference:

```
val strings = List("a", "b", "c")
for (stringWithIndex <- strings.zipWithIndex) {
  // Do something with stringWithIndex._1 (string) and stringWithIndex._2 (index)
}
```

Is there any way in the Scala syntax to have the `stringWithIndex` split into the parts (string and index) **within the `for` comprehension header**, so that readers of the code do not have to wonder at the values of `stringWithIndex._1` and `stringWithIndex._2`?

I tried the following, but it would not compile:

```
for (case (string, index) <- strings.zipWithIndex) {
  // Do something with string and index
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You almost got it:

```
scala> val strings = List("a", "b", "c")
strings: List[java.lang.String] = List(a, b, c)

scala> for ( (string, index) <- strings.zipWithIndex)
       | { println("str: "+string + " idx: "+index) }
str: a idx: 0
str: b idx: 1
str: c idx: 2
```

See, no need for `case` keyword.

Answer (score 7):

```
strings.zipWithIndex.foreach{case(x,y) => println(x,y)}
```

res:

```
(a,0)
(b,1)
(c,2)
```

Comment: Not quite what I needed, but a nice rewrite, none-the-less.

Comment: Although for that output, a single `foreach(println)` would have been enough already…